# Convert 2-d numpy array of floats to array of strings by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array, which is the output of a TensorFlow prediction. The output is looking something like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]])
```

for further processing, the 2-d NumPy array should be converted into a 1-d string array (or python list). The output should look something like this:

```
array(['01111111', '01111111', '01111111', ..., '11111111', '11111111',
       '11111111'], dtype='<U8')
```

What would be a simple or NumPy best practice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array is named `array` and numpy is imported as `np`, the following line:
`np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 1, array.astype(str))`
will suffice

Comment: Thank you, this seems the most natural and simple approach to the problem to me! However, the other answers are also valid and solve the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

output = np.array([''.join(map(str, el)) for el in arr], dtype='U8')
print(output)
```

output:

```
['011111' '011111' '011111' '111111' '111111' '111111']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply_along_axis` like below:

**Short version:**

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 1, a.astype(str))
```

**Explanation version:**

```
def join_num(r):
    return ''.join(map(str,r))

# or with lamda
# join_num = lambda x: ''.join(map(str,x))

np.apply_along_axis(join_num, 1, a)
```

Output:

```
array(['0110111', '0111111', '0110111', '1111111', '1110111', '1111111'],
      dtype='<U7')
```